# How can I retrieve "channels within a channel" on YouTube API v3

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

The YouTube channels can have lists of several "related" channels. For example, the Music channel has related Genre channels: Hip Hop, Pop, Rock, Country, etc.

Music Channel: http://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ

Related Channels to the Music Channel: http://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ/channels

I can retrieve a list of videos within a channel using the `youtube.search.list` API and I can fetch data of specific channels using `youtube.channels.list` API but I can't seem to find any API that gives me "other channels related to channel" like in the example above.

I'm pretty sure I took a look at all the APIs google is providing https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/

Is there anyway I can fetch the data I need?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the API, what you are looking for is a [ChannelSection](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channelSections) with the type `multipleChannels`.

Using your example of the Music channel, I was able to

1) [Pull a list of all channelSections](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channelSections.list?part=snippet&channelId=UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ&_h=29&)

2) Find the id of the channelSection whose type is `multipleChannels` and title is `Music Genres` (all of the way at the bottom of the linked example).

3) Using the ID from step 2 you can now [Query that specific channelSection](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channelSections.list?part=contentDetails&id=UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ.DJyIMucieug&_h=27&)

In my examples I used `snippet` for step 1 which gives you `type` and `title`.  [You could also use `contentDetails`](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channelSections.list?part=contentDetails&channelId=UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ&_h=2&) for the part field which would cut down a step, but you'd have to search through the returned list whose `contentDetails` contained a `channels` array.

Edit:

To get details for the sub-channels you can join the channel IDs together as a comma separated list and use them as the `id` parameter in a `channels.list` query.  [Here is a query returning details for the top 3 channels returned from step 3.](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list?part=snippet&id=UCUnSTiCHiHgZA9NQUG6lZkQ%252CUCE80FOXpJydkkMo-BYoJdEg%252CUCRZoK7sezr5KRjk7BBjmH6w&_h=3&)

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much. So it looks like I'd have to make an additional query using the channel IDs in the returned array in order to get the title strings?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  You can call the channels.list query with a comma separated list of the IDs for those sub-channels.  I put an example call with the top 3 sub-channels in an edit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  This doesn't seem to work for 3rd party channels such as CNN or ABCNews. For example, CNN has a list of "Related Channels" on their YouTube page, but step #1 of your answer doesn't return a multipleChannels list for CNN. Do you know how to get related channels for CNN ?

Comment: Since CNN is a User and not a built in channel, it's a little different.  You have to get the channel ID(s) for the username CNN from `channels.list`.  From there, the thing that show up in CNN's channel tab are actually subscriptions that you can pull via `subscriptions.list`.