# Choose Channel to Upload a YouTube Video

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have one Youtube Channel with about six subchannels.
How can i define the Channel in the API which i like to Upload a Video to

Something like:

```
  <?php
     $snippet->setChannelId("UCYr0l3qoK7cuZynbvDYl7Q");
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [`ChannelSection`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channelSections) with the type `multipleChannels`. As stated in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777859/how-can-i-retrieve-channels-within-a-channel-on-youtube-api-v3), using this method, you were able to:

> - [Pull a list of all channelSections](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channelSections.list?part=snippet&channelId=UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ&_h=29&)
> - Find the id of the `channelSection` whose type is `multipleChannels` and title is Music Genres (as example).
> - Using the ID from step 2 you can now [Query that specific channelSection](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channelSections.list?part=contentDetails&id=UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ.DJyIMucieug&_h=27&)

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as sub-channels in YouTube. What you probably mean is that you have *one* Google account that manages *multiple* individual channels.

When you upload a video, your application will go through the process of obtaining OAuth tokens from the API server. This is where a user action is required: The user gets directed to a webpage on which he can give his permission that the app may access his channel. **If a Google account manages multiple channels, the user must select one.** The tokens which your app receives as a result of this process are tied to the channel that the user selected and cannot be used to upload to other channels.

These tokens can then be used by your application to perform API requests like uploading videos.