# Get all videos from an Official Artist Channel

Tags: video, google-api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

It has been almost 5 years since YouTube rolled out [Official Artist Channel](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7336634). I'm surprised that this is not supported anywhere in the YouTube Data API.

What I'm trying to achieve is simple: Given a channel ID of an Official Artist Channel, retrieve all videos of the artist available on its page.

The typical solution to this problem would be to fetch a list of videos that has the channel ID:

```py
search = build_youtube_api().search()
request = search.list(
    part="snippet",
    channelId=self.id,
    maxResults=50,
    order="date",
    type="video",
)

# and then keep calling list_next() until reaching the end
```

The problem is that this method only lists some of the videos, while other videos listed on the page are still linked to the original channel before the combination.

For instance, [Adele - I Drink Wine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jDvYDzFOK9A) is listed on [Adele's official artist channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCsRM0YB_dabtEPGPTKo-gcw/videos) with a channel ID of `UCsRM0YB_dabtEPGPTKo-gcw`. However, the video can not be fetched with the method above since the channel of that video is `UComP_epzeKzvBX156r6pm1Q`, which is [AdeleVEVO](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UComP_epzeKzvBX156r6pm1Q).

Another method I tried is to use a hacky way mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777859/how-can-i-retrieve-channels-within-a-channel-on-youtube-api-v3/26982486#26982486), to find all channels that have been combined, then combine uploaded video from these channels. Sadly, this is also not working since not all artist put their old channels into the Featured Channels list (more horribly, some even place other unrelated artists in this section, which complicates the situation).

Moreover, there is no known method to distinguish whether a channel is an official artist channel or a regular video channel.

TL;DR for the API engineers: We need more granular API fields to support usage related to Official Artist Channel and music channels.

Comment: Problem is the different channels the artist *might* have - not every artist has their *VEVO* channel, so, my best guess to either to recollect all data by using a criteria you set for classify the result (*i.e. channel*) as one (un)official of the artist OR check if in YouTube Music is any info that might help you. Honestly, this is difficult because you have to rely on the public results YouTube shows on their websites (*the main one and YouTube Music*).

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes Yeah, that is precisely why I'm trying to raise the problem and hope some Google engineers can help makes some changes on their side. I personally still prefer to acquire data from the official APIs.

Comment: then, post your issue on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:186600&s=created_time:desc) as well.i

Comment: Sure, just submit a copy there. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: [Ticket # 263457038](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/263457038)